# Tensorflow ResNet model loading uses **~5 GB of RAM** - while loading from weights uses only ~200 MB

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I trained a ResNet50 model using Tensorflow 2.0 by transfer learning. I slightly modified the architecture (new classification layer) and saved the model with the ModelCheckpoint callback https://keras.io/callbacks/#modelcheckpoint during training. Training was fine. The model saved by callback takes ~206 MB on the hard drive.

To predict using the model I did:

- I started a Jupyter Lab notebook. I used `my_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('../models_using/my_model.hdf5')` for loading the model. (btw, the same occurs using IPython).
- I used the `free` linux command line tool to measure the free RAM just before the loading and after. **The model loading takes about 5 GB of RAM**.
- I saved the weights of the model and the config as json. This takes about 105 MB.
- I loaded the model from the json config and weights. This takes about ~200 MB of RAM.
- Compared the predictions of both models. Exactly the same.
- I tested the same procedure with a slightly different architeture (trained the same way) and the results were the same.

Can anyone explain the **huge RAM usage**, and the difference in size of the models on the hard drive?

Btw, given a model in Keras, can you find out the compliation procedure ( optimizer,..)? Model.summary() does not help..

**2019-12-07 - EDIT:** Thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59214089/7339840), I conducted a series of tests:

I used the `!free` command in JupyterLab to measure the available memory before and after each test. Since I `get_weights` returns a list, I used `copy.deepcopy` to really copy the objects. Note, the commands below were separate Jupyter cells and the memory comments were added just for this answer.

```py
!free

model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.hdf5', compile=True)
# 25278624 - 21491888 = 3786.736 MB used

!free

weights = copy.deepcopy(model.get_weights())
# 21491888 - 21440272 = 51.616 MB used

!free


optimizer_weights = copy.deepcopy(model.optimizer.get_weights())
# 21440272 - 21339404 = 100.868 MB used

!free

model2 = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.hdf5', compile=False)
# 21339404 - 21140176 = 199.228 MB used

!free
```

Loading the model from json:

```py
!free
# loading from json
with open('model_json.json') as f:
    model_json_weights = tf.keras.models.model_from_json(f.read())

model_json_weights.load_weights('model_weights.h5')
!free

# 21132664 - 20971616 = 161.048 MB used
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between checkpoint and JSON+Weights is in the optimizer:

- The checkpoint or `model.save()` save the optimizer and its weights (`load_model` compiles the model)
- JSON + weights doesn't save the optimizer

Unless you are using a very simple optimizer, it's normal for it to have about the same number of weights as the model (a tensor of "momentum" for each weight tensor, for instance).

Some optimizers might take two times the size of the model, because it has two tensors of optimizer weights for each tensor of model weights.

Saving and loading the optimizer is important if you want to continue training. Starting training again with a new optimizer without proper weights will sort of destroy the model's performance (at least in the beginning).

Now, the 5GB is not really clear to me. But I suppose that:

- There should be a lot of compression in saved weights
- It might have to do with also allocating memory for all the gradient and backpropagation operations

Interesting tests:

- Compression: check how much memory is used by the results of `model.get_weights()` and `model.optimizer.get_weights()`. These weights will be numpy, copied from the original tensors
- Grandient/Backpropagation: check how much memory is used by:

  - `load_model(name, compile=True)`
  - `load_model(name, compile=False)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Conducted your tests, and edited my question accordingly. I think the lion's share of the memory usage comes from Gradient/Backpropagation.
I am a little bit bothered by the fact, that the optimizer weights and the model weights together use less ram than the model on the hard drive (202 MB vs 100+50 = 150MB). Do you know an explanation?
And, do you know how to find the compilation procedure of a model if you just load it?

Comment: @MichaelS, another test you can try is to use `predict` on the model **not compiled** and see the memory increase. If the predict increases too much the memory, then it might be some overhead code to make the model ready to work.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue with a recent model that I was attempting to load. All be it this is a year old issue, so I am uncertain if my solution will work for you. However, reading through the [keras documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model) of saved model.

I found this piece of code to be very useful:

```
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
for device in physical_devices:
   tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(device, True)
```

> Can anyone explain the huge RAM usage, and the difference in size of the models on the hard drive?

It turns out in my case the loaded model was using up all of the GPU memory and causing issues so this forces it to use physical device memory or at least that is my conclusion.